# I get AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'

Tags: python, selenium, automation, bots, attributeerror

(The below code is not mine) Ive been trying to get this ixl math bot to work but everytime i run it i get

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'

Im using selenium 4.3 and the latest python version, if no one can help then at least an explanation of what this error means and how i could fix it would be appreciated,
https://github.com/debaet/IXLMultiBot?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=1D778E48B58B4E39B6F7082C77F7F797
this is the original GitHub post (not mine)

I'm fairly new to python so I only tried a few basic things like restated PATH or double "\" not a lot

its supposed to ask for username password grade and lesson link which work but after the selenium chrome windows opens and it gets gives:

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'

`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os, time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import sys
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init()

# config

#if trying yourself replace this path with your own path of chromium downloaded (with double back slashes)
PATH = ("C:\\Users\\aashu\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe") 


driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)


def main4(argv):
    lesson = input('Enter lesson link for algerba')
    while True:
        driver.get(lesson)
        time.sleep(4)
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(4)
        q1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('yui3-practiceagent-content')
        q2 = q1.text
        print(repr(q2))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button').click()
        time.sleep(4)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/button[2]').click()
        time.sleep(4)
        #change this
        answer = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[8]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]')
        ans = answer.text
        print(ans)
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[8]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button').click()


def main1(argv):
    lesson = input('Enter an 8th grade lesson link')
    while True:
        driver.get(lesson)
        time.sleep(4)
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(4)
        q1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('yui3-practiceagent-content')
        q2 = q1.text
        print(repr(q2))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button').click()
        time.sleep(4)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/button[2]').click()
        time.sleep(4)
        #change this
        answer = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[8]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[9]')
        ans = answer.text
        print(ans)
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[8]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button').click()



def main2(argv):
    lesson = input('Please Enter A 7th Grade Lesson Link: ')
    while True:
        driver.get(lesson)
        time.sleep(4)
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(4)
        q1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('yui3-practiceagent-content')
        q2 = q1.text
        print(repr(q2))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button').click()
        time.sleep(4)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/button[2]').click()
        time.sleep(4)
        answer = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[8]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div')
        ans = answer.text
        print(ans)
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[8]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button').click()
# 6th Grade
def main3(argv):
    lesson = input('Please Enter A 6th Grade Lesson Link: ')
    while True:
        driver.get(lesson)
        time.sleep(4)
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(4)
        q1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('yui3-practiceagent-content')
        q2 = q1.text
        print(repr(q2))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button').click()
        time.sleep(4)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/button[2]').click()
        time.sleep(4)
        answer = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[8]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div')
        ans = answer.text
        print(ans)
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[8]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button').click()




def op1():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print('If any of these are incorrect, bot will fail.')
    username = input('Enter Username or Email: ')
    password = input('Enter Password:  ')
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    
    
    print('do not touch the window that has just popped up. ')
    print('smart score goes up and down alot, just go afk or do something in background!')
    driver.get('https://www.ixl.com/math/grade-7/add-and-subtract-integers')
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.refresh()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qlusername"]').send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qlpassword"]').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qlsubmit"]').click()
    driver.execute_script('''window.open('',"_blank");''')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get('https://www.meta-calculator.com/scientific-calculator.php?panel-203-simple-calculator')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        variable = driver.find_element_by_class_name('old-space-indent').text
        print(variable)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
        box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/input')
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/input').send_keys(variable)
        
        answer = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/input')
        box.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
        print('the bot will now pause for 150 seconds to generate some time.')
        time.sleep(150)
        box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        answer = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]').text
        a = (answer)
        c = "="

        for char in c:
            a = a.replace(char, "")
        
        print(a)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/button[2]').click()
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('fillIn').click()
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('fillIn').send_keys(a)
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('fillIn').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        driver.refresh()

        
               

def op2():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    grade = input('Are you in 8th Grade? (Y/N): ')
    if grade == "Y":
        main1(sys.argv)
        print('You are In 8th Grade')
        print('You will be asked to Enter Your Lesson Link')
    else:
        grade2 = input('Are you in 7th Grade? (Y/N): ')
        if grade2 == "Y":
            main2(sys.argv)
            print('You are In 7th Grade')
            print('You will be asked to Enter Your Lesson Link')

        else:
            grade3 = input('Are you in 6th Grade? (Y/N): ')
        if grade3 == "Y":
            print('You are In 6th Grade')
            print('You will be asked to Enter Your Lesson Link')
            main3(sys.argv)
        else:
            print('algerba')
            main4(sys.argv)




def op4():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print('If any of these are incorrect, bot will fail.')
    username = input('Enter Username or Email: ')
    password = input('Enter Password:  ')
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def op3():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print('If any of these are incorrect, bot will fail.')
    username = input('Enter Username or Email: ')
    password = input('Enter Password:  ')
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')    

def op5():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print('If any of these are incorrect, bot will fail.')
    username = input('Enter Username or Email: ')
    password = input('Enter Password:  ')
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

    

def main():
    print('Menu: ')
    print('1. Add more time to your account')
    print('2. Scrape Answers (get answers)')
    print('3. Get Teacher Accounts')
    print('4. Auto Answer (some lessons work)')
    print('5. Credits')
    var = input('Enter an Option: ')

    # goes to the specified option 
    if var==('1'):
        op1()

    elif var==('2'):
        op2()

    elif var==('3'):
        op3()
    elif var==('4'):
        op4()

    elif var==('5'):
        op5()

    else:
        print('Please enter numbers only. If you did and still got an error, please enter a number which is listed above.')
        time.sleep(4)
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        main()



# end code

print('Welcome to The First Functional IXL BOT.')
print('DO NOT CLOSE THE CHROME WINDOW THAT IS ABOUT TO POP UP.')
print('Please wait..')

time.sleep(3)
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
main()
```

`

Thank you to anyone that helps, i will try to respond to any answers within 2-3 days

:D - Aashu,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` methods are deprecated in current Selenium versions. You need to use `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, " ")`, `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, " ")` etc. methods.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick reply, this is really helpful Do you know if i can just degrade my selenium version to a version that supports find_element_by?

Comment: Can can use Selenium 3 and it will support that but it will be better if you will learn the new syntax and use the latest Selenium versions since it supports many useful features. Also, in a future Selenium 3 will be deprecated. So, it's recommended to use Selenium 4.

Comment: Thank you so much, i think I'll just learn the new syntax.